# How to configure 3 way merge feature on compare in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, merge, visual-studio-2015, diff, merge-conflict-resolution

**Problem:** The default diff/ merge tool in visual studio 2015 (and previous versions) does not allow merging when you compare a file. It only allows you to see differences. The only occasion I'm aware of the 3 way merge option being enabled is when there is a merge conflict.

I want to see the 3 way merge option on every instance of the diff tool in Visual Studio.

**Notes:** I'm definitely not looking for an alternative tool or a 'work around' on this. I have been happily using [WinMerge](http://blog.degree.no/2013/12/using-winmerge-as-the-default-diffmerge-tool-in-visual-studio-2012/) as my merge tool which allows merging anytime you compare. I really like the vs diff tool's 3 way option and being able to use it any time I want would be a nice boost to my work flow.

Thanks!

Comment: does this guide helps: https://roadtoalm.com/2013/10/22/use-visual-studio-as-your-diff-and-merging-tool-for-local-files/

Comment: I have moved on to Git and the Git Extensions which has more diff options/ settings. That link does look promising for both vs and git. Did you get it to work for you @Tazbir?

Comment: I am using vs for git merging and comparing yes. I didn’t went through the link i provided in the earlier comment. U can test out the implementation in a test env such as vm.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone Googling Winmerge 3 way merging, Visual Studios settings for a merge are as follows:
Command:   C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe
Arguments: /e /u /wl /dl %7 /dm %8 /dr %6 %2 %3 %1 %4

Comment: while it does seem to work , unlike visual studio internal 3 way merge i can't seem to find an option in winmerge that the take the line from each file and put it the result file. (marking checkboxes on both files in visual studio merge)

Answer (score 1):

The above solution didn't work for me (I used WinMerge 2.16.2). In whatever way I ended the merge, Visual Studio said merge operation was cancelled. Final solution for me was to use /o argument:

```
/e /x /u /wl /dl %7 /dm %8 /wr /dr %6 %2 %3 %1 /o %4
```

Configuration is MINE BASE THEIRS
/x closes the compare if files are identical
/wr makes the right file readonly